# After update to Xcode 6 : Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "___gnu_f2h_ieee"

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, cpu-architecture

I have been trying to find the problem for hours with no result.
I have updated to Xcode 6 and get this error on both ioS8.0 & 7.1 since then :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___gnu_f2h_ieee", referenced from:
      _playbackCallback in Audio.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT (full build log error) :

```
Ld /Users/rjc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Acc-hjhfomxkmwbyxwbfzjbduabbhlcc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Acc.app/Acc normal armv7
cd /Users/rjc/Desktop/apps/Acc
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/rjc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Acc-hjhfomxkmwbyxwbfzjbduabbhlcc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/rjc/Desktop/apps/Acc/Acc -F/Users/rjc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Acc-hjhfomxkmwbyxwbfzjbduabbhlcc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/rjc/Desktop/apps/Acc -filelist /Users/rjc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Acc-hjhfomxkmwbyxwbfzjbduabbhlcc/Build/Intermediates/Acc.build/Debug-iphoneos/Acc.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Acc.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.1 -lCorePlot-CocoaTouch -framework CoreTelephony -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework Social -framework Accelerate -framework CoreLocation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/rjc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Acc-hjhfomxkmwbyxwbfzjbduabbhlcc/Build/Intermediates/Acc.build/Debug-iphoneos/Acc.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Acc_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/rjc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Acc-hjhfomxkmwbyxwbfzjbduabbhlcc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Acc.app/Acc
```

Comment: Can you please paste the entire error log?

Comment: @Ricky, sorry for my late reply. I have edited my question. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I also faced a very similar issue and found this. It was resolved the issue and was very helpful.
http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/35905/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-xcode-6-ios-8-beta-6/36538

Make a .c file (name is not a concern, in my case i made i386Symbols.c) and add it to the project. Then paste this.

```
//  i386Symbols.c
//  Your project
//
//  Created by Ludwig on 10/2/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *fopen$UNIX2003( const char *filename, const char *mode )
{
    return fopen(filename, mode);
}

int fputs$UNIX2003(const char *res1, FILE *res2){
    return fputs(res1,res2);
}

int nanosleep$UNIX2003(int val){
    return usleep(val);
}

char* strerror$UNIX2003(int errornum){
    return strerror(errornum);
}

double strtod$UNIX2003(const char *nptr, char **endptr){
    return strtod(nptr, endptr);
}

size_t fwrite$UNIX2003( const void *a, size_t b, size_t c, FILE *d )
{
    return fwrite(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't resolve the issue, but I have a partial workaround.
It seems that there is no `armv7` slice for many floating point functions. I assume that they will be included in a later release (or in the final release) of Xcode 6.

The `armv7s` slice is present instead: since I was debugging on an iPhone5, that uses this latter instruction set, I had just to remove the architecture from the build settings.

1. Go on your project settings, select your project.
2. Under *Build Settings*, look for the *Architectures* entry.
3. Edit it, remove `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` and replace it with `armv7s`.
4. As jcr noted, you may have to switch the `Active Architecture Only` option from `YES` to `NO`.

This will allow to build and run. Unfortunately I have no `arm64` device to test, but it might be possible that this slice is also included.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my answer. I changed the Active Architecture Only option from YES to NO and it works now. Great ! Thank you.

Comment: Because iPhone 4S uses exactly that `armv7` architecture that is missing. In this case the I think that the only option is to wait for an update and file a bug.